# Use Datediff only if other column has specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the query for showing days_left in number of days but only if the status is 'ongoing', for the status that 'done' it just need to display 'done' value

Current MySQL Query

```
SELECT
id,
due_date,
process_1,
process_2,
CASE WHEN FLOOR((IF(process_1= 'Done', 1, 0) + IF(process_2= 'Done', 1, 0))/2 * 100) = 100 THEN 'Done'
ELSE 'Ongoing' END AS status,
DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE())) AS days_left
FROM table1
```

Below is my result

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | due_date   | process_1 | process_2 | status  | days_left |
+ ----------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 10/01/2020 | ongoing   | ongoing   | ongoing |    3      |
|  2 | 10/01/2020 | done      | done      | done    |    3      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Result i want

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | due_date   | process_1 | process_2 | status  | days_left |
+ ----------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 10/01/2020 | ongoing   | ongoing   | ongoing |    3      |
|  2 | 10/01/2020 | done      | done      | done    |   done    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you have equations for calculating your `status`. You can use the same equation again to specify your `days_left`, somewhat like:

```
SELECT
id,   
due_date,
process_1,
process_2,
CASE WHEN 
  FLOOR((IF(process_1= 'Done', 1, 0) + IF(process_2= 'Done', 1, 0))/2 * 100) = 100 
  THEN 'Done'
  ELSE 'Ongoing' END AS status
CASE WHEN 
  FLOOR((IF(process_1= 'Done', 1, 0) + IF(process_2= 'Done', 1, 0))/2 * 100) = 100 
  THEN 'Done' 
  ELSE DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE())) END AS days_left
FROM table1
```